# x86 Assembly Learning Platform

Tags: assembly, x86, 64-bit, 32-bit, 6502

I've been fiddling with assembly, lately, and I've learned a lot. I was using [6502asm.com](http://6502asm.com/). [6502asm.com](http://6502asm.com/) is a javascript assembler and emulator for 6502 assembly. Here's what I like about it: Input and output is very simple and easy to understand. It supplies you with a 32x32 pixel screen, with an address space from $0200 to $05ff. Changing the color of a pixel is as simple as storing a color value (between $00 and $0f) in one of the screen's addresses ($0200 being the top left, and $05ff being the bottom right.) That was a lot of fun to mess around with, but it's 8-bit, and a 32x32 screen doesn't have a lot of room. I was wondering if there's anything like [6502asm.com](http://6502asm.com/) for 32/64-bit assembly instead of 8-bit. (It doesn't have to be in the browser, just anything that's similar.) Also, I'd prefer if it used nasm, but it's not a requirement. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Javascript x86 emulators exist (eg http://bellard.org/jslinux/), but I don't know of any that offer such a nice sandbox.

Comment: MS-DOS. The screen is typically either 80x25 text, or 640x480 graphics. Present day, you'd typically use the DOS box in Windows XP, probably itself running inside of a virtual machine. You can use the editor and assembler of your choice (MASM, FASM, NASM, TASM, etc.)

Comment: Thanks, guys. Forgot to mention I'm on Linux though.

Comment: You can still run something like [FreeDOS](http://www.freedos.org/) in a VM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Jasmin](http://www.lrr.in.tum.de/%7Ejasmin/index.html) helps you learn x86 assembly but it doesn't have any graphical representation. But you can see the registers and memory change as you execute your x86 code.

If you feel 6502asm.com limited with 32x32 pixels, why not try "the real thing", meaning a macro assembler in an IDE that you can run on an emulator?

For instance, the following combination:

- [dasm](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dasm-dillon/) or [Kick Assembler](http://www.theweb.dk/KickAssembler/Main.php), two cross-platforms 65xx assemblers
- [WUDSN IDE](http://www.wudsn.com/index.php/ide), a nice IDE with code completion, error highlighting, bundled as a plugin for Eclipse
- [VICE](http://vice-emu.sourceforge.net/), an emulator for C64/128, VIC20...

Of course, you 'll need to learn the intricacies of the target 8-bit machine of your choice, but IMO that's even more fun. On the C64 for instance, you get 320x200 graphics, sprites with collision detection, 40x25 text display. If you get your hand on actual hardware, you might even consider running your program on it.

Comment: Ah, very informative answer! Going to have a lot of fun messing with all this, even though it's been two years since this question was posted. :)

Answer (score 0):

After a little more googling, I found notch's (creator of minecraft) new game, 0x10c. It's a space game with where you control a space ship, and inside the ship is an ingame, programmable computer called the dcpu-16, which you program to control every aspect of your ship. The game is not released yet, however there are several emulators and assemblers for the dcpu-16 already made. I compiled the one [here](https://github.com/DCPUTeam/DCPUToolchain), and assembled and ran a test program (conways game of life,) and it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Here, you can find a very interesting open source JS project for you.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/jsdosbox/